# How do i store user login details in spring session?

Tags: spring

I want to store user login details in the session using spring mvc. That login Details I want to use another controller. can anyone explain with code?

Comment: Use Spring Security.

Comment: Actually new to spring security. Can you give me small example...

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5//hellomvc.html

Comment: In that link...there is no session description?

Comment: can you post code snippet?

Comment: Spring security will handle the session you can get the User information from SecurityContext. If you need example code you wont get it in StackOverflow. I advice you to search in github.com for spring security you will get lot for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use session storage of browser

1. HTML5 localStorage -

Stores data with no expiration date.The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.This is compatible from IE8 onwards.

Pros -

1. Client Storage Solution
2. Session data is held on the server where it remains under your direct control.
3. Preferable to store data on an ongoing basis.
4. Perfect for storing non sensitive data
5. ease of use for web developers:
6. Is capable of returning most primitive Javascript objects but not Array and Object. Can use JSOn to serialize though
7. The amount of space it provides: the specs default the disk space quota decision to the user agent (i.e. the web browser developers) and most of them offer no less than 5 or   10 MB to be stored per domain. This means we can store more than just basic user/session info on the client-side: user preference settings, localization data, temporary offline   storage for batching server writes and much more.

Cons:

1.Not supported by legacy systems and browsers
2. Can be cleared by the user so you should not rely on the continuing existence of data.
3. Data can easily be manipulated from the browser

2. HTML5 serverStorage:

Stores data for one session.The sessionStorage object is equal to the localStorage object, except that it stores the data for only one session. The data is deleted when the user closes the browser window. Compatible only from IE8 onwards.

Pros:

1. Client Storage Solution
2. Session data is held on the server where it remains under your direct control.
3. Perfect for storing non sensitive data
4. Is capable of returning most primitive Javascript objects but not Array and Object. Can use JSOn to serialize though
5. ease of use for web developers:
   6.the amount of space it provides: the specs default the disk space quota decision to the user agent (i.e. the web browser developers) and most of them offer no less than 5 or 10 MB to be stored per domain. This means we can store more than just basic user/session info on the client-side: user preference settings, localization data, temporary offline storage for batching server writes and much more.

Cons:

1.Not supported by legacy systems and browsers
2. Can survive page reloads but still wont persist beyond the session
3. Can be cleared by the user so you should not rely on the continuing existence of data.
4. Data can easily be manipulated from the browser

3. TempData in MVC

TempData is session, so they're not entirely different. However, the distinction is easy to understand, because TempData is for redirects, and redirects only. So when you set some message in TempData and then redirect, you are using TempData correctly.

Pros:

1. Useful in Redirects
2. Can be used to pass data between Controllers in MVC

Cons:

1.TempData is cleared out at the end of the next request. You should use TempData when the data needs only to persist between two requests

4. Store Results in a cookie

Use cookies to store the data.

Pros:

1. Client Storage Solution
2. Session data is held on the server where it remains under your direct control.
3. Have some protection associated with it like authenticated cookies

Cons:

1.Only allow you to store strings
2. Susceptible to tampering
3. As cookies are used for authentication purposes and persistence of user data, all cookies valid for a page are sent from the browser to the server for every request to the same domain
4. For this reason cookies should not be used to store large amounts of information.
5. data-capacity limitations

5. Session Variables

Use session variables to store data in the session.

Pros:

1. Best to be used for anything sensitive or secure as it is completely server side
2. Does not expire - it will be valid for all requests, not a single redirect.
3. Good for storing small amounts of data

Cons:

1. scalability - server resources are required for each user for the duration of the session, and that any data needed client side must be sent with each request. As the server has no way of knowing if a user navigates to another site or closes their browser, session data must expire after a given time to avoid all server resources being taken up by abandoned sessions
2. You can "steal" sessions from other users, so may cause some security issues as well